# Relation hasOne work in Controller but not in blade

Tags: php, laravel

Controller method:

```
public function panorama($id)
{
    $order = ClientOrder::find($id);
    $products = ClientProduct::where('client_order_id', $order->id)->with('product')->get();
    $conteo = count($products);

    return view('add.preview.work_panorama', compact('order', 'products', 'conteo'));
}
```

Relation in Model:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'id', 'product_id');
}
```

View on blade:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        {{ $product->product->name }}
        @foreach($product->processes as $process)
            <li>-{{ $process->name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

In the view the $process->name work but $product->product->name print a white space, but in the controller print the product name.

Comment: You means your `$product->product->name` and `$process->name` are same but `$product->product->name` return white space, right?

Comment: Can you post your Model Code for Product?

Comment: what error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

It is because with returns a collection object from the database. Try using it with index like this.

```
 {{ $product->product[0]->name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with compact and when i changed it with the below code it worked.

```
return \View::make('add.preview.work_panorama')->with('order', $order)
                                               ->with('products', $products)
                                               ->with('conteo', $conteo);
```